# Need help overriding default padding

Tags: css, padding

I'm a total newbie at learning code and I'm struggling with what is probably a very simple code, but I just can't get it right.  I'm trying to update my company's website (I'm not a web designer or coder) to remove some excessive padding between two content areas and I've tried multiple different types of code that are available on the internet (and some here) to no avail.  I used the inspect web page tool and I can see that the default settings reside in the css for the site, but I'm not advanced enough to know if my editing the precise padding will affect other areas of the website.  Is it possible to apply code that would override the default for just that specific page and if so, what would be the correct code?  The extra padding is between here:

```
<div class="row body-copy">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
[[*content]]
</div>
```

and here:

```
<section class="leaders">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
```

This is the beginning part of the code from the page template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Head Tag -->
[[$head-tag]]


<body>
[[$gtm]]

<!-- Navigation -->
    [[$navigation]]

    <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->

    <section class="top">
        <div class="container">

            [[$top-page-info]]


            <div class="row body-copy">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    [[*content]]
</div>
                </div>
            </div><!--end row-->
        </div><!--end container-->
    </section>
 <section class="leaders">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


                [[!getPage? 
                    &amp;elementClass=`modSnippet` 
                    &amp;element=`getResources` 
                    &amp;parents=`14`
```

etc.

UPDATED WITH SECTION OF CSS THAT CONTROLS THIS AREA OF THE PAGE:

```
    /*-------------------------------------CONTENT-------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.breadcrumbs {
    padding:27px 15px 10px 0;
    color:#ACACAC;
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;    */
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    text-align: right;
}

.breadcrumbs p{
    margin:0;
    font-size:10px; 
}

.breadcrumbs a {
    /*padding: 20px 0;*/
    color:#a3a3a3;
}
.breadcrumbs ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 11px;

}

.breadcrumbs ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.breadcrumbs a.B_currentCrumb,
.breadcrumbs li.B_currentCrumb,
.breadcrumbs .B_lastCrumb {
    color:#00AEEF; 
}

section {
    padding: 50px 0 50px;
}

section.top {
    padding: 120px 0 50px;
}

section.services-top {
    padding:120px 0 10px;
}

.page-info {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00AEEF; 
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.page-info.second {
    border-bottom: none; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: bottom;
}

section.dark {
    background-color: #292929;
    color:#c8c8c8;
     padding: 50px 0;   
}

section.medium {
    background-color: #9d9fa2;
     padding: 60px 0;
}

section.light {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    padding: 60px 0;
}

section.dark-blue {
    /*background-color: #005b7d;*/
    /*background-color: #00749e;*/
    background-color: #005b7d;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color:#cacaca;
        font-weight: 300;
}

div.dark-blue {
    /*background-color: #005b7d;*/
    /*background-color: #00749e;*/
    background-color: #005b7d;
    padding: 25px;
    color:#cacaca;
        font-weight: 300;
}


ul {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

ul li{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.nav li { margin-bottom: 0px; }

ul.pageList {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

ul.pageList li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

a:hover > img {
    opacity:0.5; 
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'nudista-web',sans-serif;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.call-to-action h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
}



.clear {
    clear: both;
}

h1 {
    color: #00AEEF;
    font-weight: 300;
   /* padding-bottom: 5px;*/
    display: inline-block;
  /*  border-bottom: 1px solid #00AEEF;*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
   /* margin: 0 0 30px 0;*/
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2 {
    color: #00AEEF;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;

}

h3 {
    color: #00AEEF;
    color:#555;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

section.dark-blue h3 {
    color: #00AEEF;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

h4 {
    /*color: #00749e;*/
    line-height: 1.35;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.no-gutter > [class*=col-] {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

section.dark ul{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-image: url('../images/little-blue-arrow.png');
}

.body-copy ul {
        padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 25px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-image: url('../images/little-blue-arrow.png');
}


.media{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a3a3a3;
}

.media h4 {
    /*color:#00749e;*/
}

.media p {
    /*color:#888;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.media a {
    color:#000;
    /*margin: 0 0 15px 5px;*/
    display: inline-block;
text-decoration: underline;
}

.services a h3{
    color:#00AEEF;
    margin-top: 15px;
}



section.services {
    padding:40px 0 10px;
}

.service-callout.vanish p.btn {
    display:none;
}

.service-callout {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.leader-callout {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    min-height: 740px;
}

.service-callout h3{
color: #00AEEF;
margin-top: 15px;
}


.leaders h3 {
    color: #00AEEF;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

.leaders h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:5px 0 10px 0;
}

.job-list ul  {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    }

.job-list ul li {
    border-bottom:1px solid #003b51;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.job-list ul li a{
    color:#f1f1f1;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.job-list ul li a:hover{
    color:#3fc0eb;

}
```

hope this is enough of the css!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want to adjust the padding for either the leaders section, top section or both. In your css file, add this at the bottom and adjust values accordingly.

```
.leaders {
  padding: 0;
}

.top {
  padding: 0;
}
```

If you want to adjust only top and bottom padding, you can use `padding: (some amount) 0;` This will set your right and left padding to 0, and your top and bottom to some amount.

Keep in mind that your problem could be related to margins as well. Margin is the space between each element, and padding is the padding **within** the element. It can be hard to tell what's what just by looking at it. Changing the color of the background can help with identifying this.

If you share your css file maybe I can be of more help.

Comment: I'm hesitant to share the css because of company confidentiality issues. (I honestly don't know if it contains anything that would be considered confidential & I don't want to risk posting it publicly if I don't need to.)

Comment: I really am trying to avoid editing the css if possible because I don't know if it will affect another page on the website.  Is it possible to apply code to the page template where I need to remove the extra padding?  I've tried the following code right on the template, hoping that it would override the css but it didn't work.

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12; padding-bottom: 0px">
     
     [[*content]]
    </div>

Comment: I would avoid adding <style> tags to your html if you also have an external stylesheet. Chances are your CSS file will not have anything that even identifies your company. Maybe something at the header or footer? Your HTML files are more likely to contain something that might violate an NDA.

Comment: I updated my original post and added a the content section of the css.  Is that enough?

Comment: That should work. On the `section.top {` portion, change the "50px" padding value to something smaller. That should help a bit with the gap you're experiencing. Also, look for something named `section.leaders {` Is there anything like that containing padding values?

Comment: I changed the section.top padding and also section padding as you recommended but it didn't change anything.  (Which is strange because when I used the inspect tool, that's how I figured out the default setting was in the css filed.) Not sure why it didn't work.  There is another section in the css that relates to the leader-callout:
    }

    .leader-callout {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        min-height: 740px;
    }

Comment: leader-callout is it's own class. Are you sure that the CSS file you linked is the one being referenced at the top of your html file?

Comment: I tried updating the margin-bottom: 40px to 10px and it also had no effect on the page.  What else could be controlling that?

Comment: Maybe there is another reference to the section elements further down below that overrides existing padding values?

Comment: As a newbie, I'm going to answer no.  :)  I assumed it was this css file as it is the one referenced when I used the inspect web page tool and it even referenced the exact css line.  When I edited the code in the tool, it modified the spacing on the page.  But when I actually edit the css file, nothing changes. 
 There are quite a few other css files in my list.  How would I discern which one is controlling this?

Comment: I just noticed you're working with templates. It might vary depending on how that is setup. If it was done right, the css file will have a name that makes sense based on whatever type of page you're trying to edit. If not and you're not sure where to start, you could always change the background color to something obvious and see if anything changes.

Comment: "At the top of the html page..."  <<<And this is where I feel like an idiot.  I have no idea what the html page is.  Sorry.  I have the css files that contain all the code.  I have all the templates for the individual pages, and I have all the pages with content.  ?

Comment: I meant the top of the HTML file, but with template files you won't have much. Just try to determine which CSS file is relevant to the page you're trying to edit. Once you find it you can look for the section.top and section.leaders portion.

Comment: Code from the template page is what's in my original post.  That's why I'm lost.  The section that you first pointed me to in the css is what *should* be controlling it.  That's what matches the section when I use the inspect tool and highlight both sections above and below the padded space.  In the inspect tool, I adjusted the px on both sections and it adjusted correctly (but it's only a temporary view).  In the real css (as referenced in the inspect tool and what you pointed me too also), changing the px didn't adjust anything.  But I truly thank you for your patience and direction.